# For some reason my LinkedList addObj() method is adding the first object in the list twice

Tags: linked-list

For some reason my LinkedList addObj() method is adding the first object in the list twice

here is my method

```
public <T> void addObj(T obj)
{   

    if(head == null)
        head = new Node(obj, null);

    Node t = head;
    while(t.next != null)
        t = t.next;

    t.next = new Node (obj,null);

}
```

the output always dispays

OBJ1
OBJ1
OBJ2
OBJ3
OBJ4

Comment: You don't exit the method after you create the initial head node.  So, the first time you create a node, you create the head with your object, then you go on to add the same object to a new node and add that node to your head.  You should also learn how to debug.

Comment: Awesome!  So silly. thanks for you help, appreciate it